# Is there a way to change the toolbar button name in DataGrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

I have made a custom toolbar

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  )
}
```

But I'd like to change the names when displayed, not to be Columns, Filters, Density, Export, is there any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the `localeText` prop of `DataGrid`/`DataGridPro`, see all the translation keys and its default values [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/blob/HEAD/packages/grid/_modules_/grid/constants/localeTextConstants.ts):

```
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  localeText={{
    toolbarColumns: "my columns",
    toolbarFilters: "my filters",
    toolbarDensity: "my density",
    toolbarExport: "my export"
  }}
  components={{
    Toolbar: CustomToolbar
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you so much, been struggling on this for hours

Comment: Done it, i'm new around here, and yes it solved the issue, thanks once again!

Comment: MUI X Data Grid localization docs for v6.11.0 (which include a link to the translation keys):
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/localization/

Answer (score 0):

how could i change button to `iconButton` in DataGrid

```
<DataGrid
        onRowModesModelChange={onRowModesModelChange}
        initialState={initialDevicesTableState}
        processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        pageSizeOptions={pageSizeOptions}
        onRowEditStop={onRowEditStop}
        rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
        isRowSelectable={() => false}
        localeText={{
            toolbarFilters: '',
            toolbarExport: ""
        }}
        slotProps={slotProps}
        density='compact'
        loading={loading}
        columns={columns}
        slots={slots}
    />
```