# Is there a way to customize the text in the GridToolbarButtons?

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

I am trying to remove the text of these buttons for a smaller device. I expected there to be a prop I can customize to change the text of the buttons. I have tried going through and changing the props that might work. No luck so far.

```
<GridToolbarColumnsButton />
<GridToolbarFilterButton />
<GridToolbarDensitySelector />
<GridToolbarExport />
```

[GridToolbarButtons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phUEY.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to change the toolbar button name in DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495064/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-toolbar-button-name-in-datagrid)