# Is there a way to change the toolbar button name in Mui-x Datagrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  )
}
```

Here, In this want to change Density name to something else. Is this possible? How?
I am trying this way but unable to do it.

```
<GridToolbarDensitySelector 
                GridLocaleText={{
                    toolbarDensity: 'Layout',
                    toolbarDensityLabel: 'Layout',
                    toolbarDensityCompact: 'Compact',
                    toolbarDensityStandard: 'Standard',
                    toolbarDensityComfortable: 'Comfortable',
                }}
/>
```

The answer with example and code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to change the toolbar button name in DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495064/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-toolbar-button-name-in-datagrid)